# How to make a sample/note sustained or long in Reason 4?

Tags: sampling

In Reason 4, some notes play as long as the red bar in the editing window continues. Others have just a single touch with no release and no matter how long the bar, they don't sound continuously.

How do I achieve this effect in such cases?

For example, I loaded a sample in the NN-XT device (it's a simple "uh-huh"), but I'd like to transform it, make it sustained, so it gets longer as much as I want.

Basically I'm talking about the difference between **pa!** vs **paaaaaaaaaa...**

Answer (score 2):

I found this out today. Look at the knobs under the sampling window (root, tune start...etc)
Turn the "Play mode" to FW-LOOP. Calibrate the "loop start/end" to your liking. i how that gave some insight.

Comment: Is it possible to let the sound sustain even if the note is not pressed (like when having a pedal) ?

Answer (score 1):

Increase the release time on the sampler, it's on the bottom right hand corner or at the top in the Global Controls. It may or may not sound the way you expect or hope it would sound. It's the only thing that can be done within NN-XT itself, as far as I know, to increase the sustain of the note. The sample will greatly influence how nice this turns out.

Comment: You mean in the AMV Envelope? I put it to maximum but it doesn't work...

Comment: @Alenanno Try switching the play mode to Looped, it's an option under the sampling window. I don't have Reason in front of my right now but when I do I'll update this if that doesn't work.

Comment: I tried that but the note (sample) is repeated, not stretched/sustained/longer.

Comment: I'm still not sure how to do this in older versions of Reason but it's easy to do in Reason 7.